# Angular 9 Reverse element scroll direction

Tags: angular, scroll

I have a problem with reversing scroll direction on element in Angular 9 application.

I'm making a chat app, and I had to use css hacks for showing elements properly on Firefox browser. Because of those hacks on Firefox I have reverted scroll direction. Once I scroll my mouse up my window scroll goes down and once I scroll mouse down, my window scroll goes up. I have totally no idea, how can I reverse it. I don't want to change anything in my css files, I need to implement it only in my ts file.

Is this even possible to achieve that? Thanks!